# Godot, trying to apply impulse to a projectile

Tags: gdscript, godot4

I have a world scene, that has a player.tscn in it, the player is a cannon, the cannon spawns a projectile, but I cannot seem to get the projectile(RigidBody2d) to move, it will drop with gravity enabled so i know its not set to static.

This is the player.tscn,

```
extends CharacterBody2D

@export var projectile : PackedScene = preload("res://projectile.tscn")

var cannon_rotation_speed = 10
var cannon: Sprite2D

var max_angle:float = -87.0
var min_angle:float = 4.0

var projectile_speed:float = 100.0




func _ready():
    set_physics_process(true)
    cannon = $Cannon

func _process(delta):
    if Input.is_action_pressed("aim_up"):
        rotate_cannon(-cannon_rotation_speed * delta)
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("aim_down"):
        rotate_cannon(cannon_rotation_speed * delta)
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Velocity_Increase"):
        projectile_speed += 1
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("Velocity_Decrease"):
        projectile_speed -= 1


func rotate_cannon(angle):
    var new_angle = cannon.rotation_degrees + angle
    if new_angle > max_angle and new_angle < min_angle:
        cannon.rotation_degrees = new_angle
        
        
func _unhandled_input(event):
    if event.is_action_pressed("shoot"): 
        shoot()

func shoot():
    var b = projectile.instantiate()
    owner.add_child(b)
    var muzzle_transform = $Cannon/Muzzle.global_transform
    b.global_transform = muzzle_transform
    var direction = Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(deg_to_rad(cannon.rotation_degrees)) # Convert degrees to radians
    var impulse_direction = direction.normalized()
    b.apply_impulse(Vector2.ZERO, impulse_direction * projectile_speed * b.mass)
```

and this is the projectile.tscn,

```
extends RigidBody2D


# Called when the node enters the scene tree for the first time.
func _ready():
    set_physics_process(true)

# Called every frame. 'delta' is the elapsed time since the previous frame.
func _process(delta):
    pass

func _on_body_entered(body):
    queue_free()
```

I have tried setting the physics_process for both .tscn, changed speed values to extremes. but getting no change.

Comment: No idea. The code looks OK at a glance. The only thing I notice is that you call `set_physics_process` which tells Godot to call `_physics_process` but there is no `_physics_process` so it would be a waste. Starting ffrom Godot 3 you do not have to call `set_physics_process(true)` unless you called `set_physics_process(false)` first. *It was necesary to call `set_fixed_process(true)` in Godot 2.*

Comment: Yeah with the Set_physics_process, I was at the point of throwing everything at the wall to see what sticks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so I added, impulse_direction * projectile_speed to an impulse var first and used that, that fixed my issue, looks like rotated was initially receiving a Vector2 when it requires a float.

```
func shoot():
var b = projectile.instantiate()
owner.add_child(b)
var muzzle_transform = $Cannon/Muzzle.global_transform
b.global_transform = muzzle_transform
var direction = Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(deg_to_rad(cannon.rotation_degrees)) # Convert degrees to radians
var impulse_direction = direction.normalized()
var impulse = impulse_direction * projectile_speed
b.apply_impulse(impulse)
```